# SQL error on multiple joins: "Encountered INNER. Was expecting one of "and"... "except"

Tags: sql, inner-join, outer-join

SQL CODE BELOW -
I am trying to join 4 tables. Error with the last inner join. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last `INNER JOIN` is out of place.  The order of elements in a SQL query is that joins come before the `WHERE` clause, and there is only one `WHERE` clause.  End your query with this and the error should go away:

```
INNER JOIN Cust c
    ON v.scnum = c.cnbr
INNER JOIN cont d
    ON c.cnbr = d.cnbr
WHERE
    current_date - c.cust_acct_crte_dt <= 730 AND
    d.role = 'PS';
```